# How to make chart for ethereum smart contract

Tags: javascript, chart.js, ethereum

I have here a smart contract and a I want to make a chart for this smart Contract address
0xE462CbEE0cd420f6c199B0194B1D8D93Fb5e7720  and for "total supply"

I want the chart to update as soon as a transaction goes in our out

How can i implement this in chartjs?

I have here the html canvas

```
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

and than the js file with this

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});

//and here is the data from my smart contract 
var supply = await contract.methods.totalSupply().call()

// and than i output it in my UI like this
document.getElementById('contractBalanceSnet').innerHTML = supply/100000000
```

How can i now use the data totalSupply for the chart?

Comment: Where is your data supposed to come from? Or is that what you're asking?

Comment: the data comes from the smart contract- i dont know how to get this data from the smart contract in my case fthe data from totalSupply into the chart

Comment: Try figure that out first. Until you've got the data you can't do anything with the chart, and SO isn't for suggesting off site resources. Google "ethereum API", there are a load of them, I'm sure you'll be able to find one that has what you need

Comment: i already have access to the totalsupply in my contract i just dont know how to get the "totalSupply" into the chart. i update my question

Comment: Provide an example of what the `supply` data looks like: `console.log(supply);`

Comment: undefined - the problem is i cant access supply outside the function

Comment: That's because your `totalSupply()` function returns a promise. Docs for away (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await). Share the code for it `totalSupply()`

Comment: var contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi,address);
var supply = await contract.methods.totalSupply().call();
document.getElementById('contractBalanceSnet').innerHTML = supply;